# whats the issue with ajax query , there is no connections and the success queries laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my add to cart ajax requests which do not result in a laravel project on which I am working. The problem is that locally everything works perfectly well:

```
 async function add_cart(row_id,variant) {
    $('#cover-spin').show(0);
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: APP_URL + "/cart/add/" + row_id,
        data: {quantity: 1,variants: variant},
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#search-keyword').keyup();
                refreshCartPage();
                updateCartCount();
                setTimeout(function(){ $('#cover-spin').hide(0); }, 1000);
                toastr.options.closeButton = true;
toastr.success("Produit ajouter au panier");
            } else {
                refreshCartPage();
                setTimeout(function(){ $('#cover-spin').hide(0); }, 1000);
                toastr.options.closeButton = true;
                toastr.error("Quelque chose c'est mal passé");
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            refreshCartPage();
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#cover-spin').hide(0); }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

here is the link of the site in question shoppypagne.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: i can suggest use route name in ajax "url: APP_URL + "/cart/add/" + row_id" or "url()->to('cart/add')